# How to get name of process work ( tasklist ) c++

Tags: c++, windows, process, tasklist

I want to know how
Know the names of the process by working through (tasklist)
And search for the name of the process

Look like the process that works
A process called "skype.exe"

with c++

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Please describe your problem more.

Comment: As in tasklist.exe? use enumprocesses+getmodulebasename ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx